# Texify problem received in yap file

Tags: texify, yap

I m receiving the following message at my yap file when i texify

TeX output 2019.04.29:1550' -> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin\dvips.exe: ! Couldn't find header file arial.pfb.
Note that an absolute path or a relative path with .. are denied in -R2 mode.

Comment: well something in your document requesting arial.pfb as a resource. If it is a graphic it is probably better to remake it.

Comment: Can we add a package for arial.pfb

Comment: No, that's a font, and it is not in texlive, you need a local version.